# How to define namespaces for xpath using the xqilla commandline tool?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to use some xpath expressions to extract info from an XML file that looks like this (it is an OAI-PMH protocol response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/
                             http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
  <responseDate>2013-10-11T09:24:55Z</responseDate>
  <request verb="ListRecords" metadataPrefix="oai_dc">http://request.url.com/oai</request>
  <ListRecords>
    <record>
      <header>
        <identifier>oai:identifier:item1</identifier>
        <datestamp>2012-06-07T12:03:53Z</datestamp>
        <setSpec>set:identifier</setSpec>
      </header>
      <metadata>
        <oai_dc:dc
            xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/
                                http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
          <dc:title xml:lang="en-US">Title</dc:title>
          <dc:creator>creator</dc:creator>
          <dc:description xml:lang="en-US">abstract</dc:description>
          <dc:publisher xml:lang="en-US">publisher</dc:publisher>
          <dc:contributor xml:lang="en-US"></dc:contributor>
          <dc:date>2011-10-18</dc:date>
          <dc:type xml:lang="en-US"></dc:type>
          <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
          <dc:identifier>identifier</dc:identifier>
          <dc:source xml:lang="en-US">source</dc:source>
        </oai_dc:dc>
      </metadata>
    </record>
    <record>
     ...
    </record>
     ...
  </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Ultimately I will have to write some Java code to do this, but I'd like to know more about the xpath and namespaces and for that reason I use the command line tool xqilla.

After some research (eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804055/problem-running-xpath-query-with-namespaces)) and many failed attempts I tried the following expression:

```
//*[local-name()='title']
```

but I get the following error:

```
:1:22: error: No namespace for prefix 'xs' [err:XPST0081]
```

Could someone point me to the right direction please? The documentation of [xqilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/Documentation) has not proven very helpful so far.

Thanks.

Edit: Since the title is not exactly what is being asked here, a follow up (and more general) question would be how does one define namespaces in general using xqilla? Because if I try the expression:

```
//dc:title
```

the error I get is

```
/tmp/foo.xq:1:3: error: No namespace for prefix 'dc' [err:XPST0081]
```

I am running xqilla like this:

```
xqilla -p -i oai_response.xml foo.xq
```

Comment: Are you using XQuery or XPath? Because in XQuery you can just generally use `declare namespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";`

Comment: Interesting, but I am using XPath only. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, then I have no idea. For XPath, namespaces have to be defined in advance, before it is interpreted. For a command line XPath interpreter I would expect a command line switch to declare namespaces. I've looked through the documentation of xquilla for a while and did not find anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

XQilla can do XPath but by default it uses XQuery.

You can create an xquery file like this, eg: my.file.xquery

```
declare namespace dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
doc("my.file.xml")//dc:title
```

And then run it

```
xqilla my.file.xquery
```

If you want to use only xpath i'm not sure how to specify the namespace
What you can do is use the namespace wildcard. So put this in my.file.xpath

```
//*:title
```

And run it with

```
xqilla -p -i my.file.xpath my.file.xml
```