# XPATH expression with local-name in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I'm trying to select the PRICE AMOUNT node in the following XML string:

```
<ARTICLE mode="new">
        <SUPPLIER_AID>KDWBWZC0-EI1RE</SUPPLIER_AID>
        <ARTICLE_DETAILS>
            <DESCRIPTION_SHORT>Test</DESCRIPTION_SHORT>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG>Test</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
            <MANUFACTURER_NAME>Symantec</MANUFACTURER_NAME>
        </ARTICLE_DETAILS>
        <ARTICLE_ORDER_DETAILS>
            <ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT>
        </ARTICLE_ORDER_DETAILS>
        <ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS>
            <ARTICLE_PRICE price_type="net_customer">
                <PRICE_AMOUNT>8.16</PRICE_AMOUNT>
                <PRICE_CURRENCY>EUR</PRICE_CURRENCY>
            </ARTICLE_PRICE>
        </ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS>
    </ARTICLE>
```

My Code to select the node works well, if I manually remove the namespaces. I just do the following:

```
xmln.SelectSingleNode("ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS/ARTICLE_PRICE/PRICE_AMOUNT").InnerText
```

But the problem is, the XML contains namespaces that I need to ignore. So I would like to use the local-name function. But I don't know how to do that. Could any of you help me out?

Thanks and best regards,
Mark

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804055/problem-running-xpath-query-with-namespaces

Comment: Have you tried adding an Imports <xmlns:xmlNamespacePrefix = "xmlNamespaceName"> to your code?